# If no light falls upon something, why is it white?

Tags: visible-light

In biology, I have been told the plume of a seed is white as no light falls upon it. Is this the case for all objects with no light shining on it?

Comment: Are they making a biological statement in that light would cause the plume to change its chemistry and produce pigmentation?

Comment: I think it is a biological statement.

Comment: let me elaborate: an onion inside is white, it grows underground where no light reaches it to energize the cells that will give color. Green onions are green outside and white inside where no light is reaching the layers. So there must be a bioligical process "light +some-type-of-cell=color"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about biology, not physics.

Answer (score 4):

The plume is white because it does not develop Chlorophyll until stimulated to do so by being exposed to light. Seeds are typically underground, where it is dark. If you dig up a seedling and look at it in the light, it is white. A  while after it reaches the surface, it turns green.

Comment: Indeed. Poster would probably have seen potato sprouts or bean sprouts?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever told you this was probably trying to say that the plume of a seed *absorbs* no light, and so scatters different wavelengths roughly equally. It is true that all objects that scatter light of different wavelengths equally will appear white, this is essentially an effect of how your eye & neurochemistry works.  If light of all different visible wavelengths hits your eye, it stimulates all the different receptors in your eye, and the resulting stimulation is interpreted as the color white.